# How do i add the numbers of multiples in a list?

Tags: python, list

Im trying to find the number of multiples in a list while divided by a number provided from the user. For example the list [12, 5] and the user input is 3 so the output would be 5, because int(12/3) + int(5/3) = 5.

```
def multiple(first_list, dividing_num):
     quotient = []
     for i in list(first_list):
      quotient = i // dividing_num
      i += quotient
     return i
print(multiple([9, 18, 2, 20, 21], 4))
#the output should be 16
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: `sum(i // dividing_num for i in first_list)`?

Comment: What is the point of `list()` in `list(first_list)`? You don't need to convert a list into a list.

Answer (score 1):

few changes in your for loop

```
summ = 0
for i in first_list:
    quotient = i // dividing_num
    summ += quotient
return summ
```

`quotient = []` can be removed

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use a very short comprehension here:

```
l = [12, 5]
n = 3
sum(i//n for i in l)
```

output: `5`